# Awk program creating very large negative number when trying to add up values from csv file

Tags: awk

Here's my program with the unnecessary to the issue things taken out:

```
BEGIN{
   count = 0
   total = 0
   FS = ","
 } 
{
for(i=1; i<10; i++)
    count += $i;
total += count
count = 0
}
END{ print(total) }
```

The count when it prints out comes out as the very large negative number 
-2519999999999999782145076764868608
when I'm expecting a positive number.

How would I go about fixing this? I don't think it's a concatenation issue because there are more values in the csv than in the printed out number.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Try running awk (gawk) with the option --bignum

Comment: @glennjackman no it was supposed to be count += $i;

Comment: The only way that script will output a very large negative number is if your input file contains very large negative numbers. I strongly suspect the problem is in some other part of your script that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it

Instead of += the total, 
I'm doing

```
for(i=0; i<count; i++)
     total ++
```

it may not be the prettiest but it gets the right answer!

Comment: whatever is going on, if that produces different output than the script in your question then you're masking some problem that's going to come back and bite you later.

Comment: you should take the time to create 1 line of sample data, and experiment so you understand the difference between `count += $i` and `total ++`. Or add debug messages, i.e. `print "total=" total "\tcount=" count`. Also, resetting `count=0` for each itteration of the loop seems counter-productive when you're using `count += $i`, You could just write as `count=$i`. Good luck.

Comment: Adding ten $I value where `I` is from 1 to 10 is not the same as adding 10 times 1. First is adding the value of the field number `I` where the second add 1.